# Playframework: Internationalisation within Akka and Unit-Test

Tags: unit-testing, internationalization, akka, playframework-2.2, message

I'm currently working on a scheduled Akka-Task which sends Emails to customers.
Part of those Emails are rendered with scala-Templates that are inserted like this:

```
emailData.add("address", views.html.shared.formated_address.render(item).body());
```

formated_address.scala.html is heavily using Message-helper (play.api.i18n.Messages).

In a application-context, the internationalisation works flawless (taking the Language defined in Context).
Unfortunately, rendering the same Template from within an Akka-Task or Unit-Test results in translation-keys that are not translated.

I know that it must be possible to force a Language by overwriting the implicit Lang value, but had no success doing that.

One solution that came to my mind was, to start a fakeApplication, but this seems an overkill for a lightweight Akka-Task.

Any Ideas how to work-around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Here comes the answer to my own question.
While analysing Library-Code, I found out that implicit Lang (which is used by Messages-Helper) is usually set by Cookie PLAY_LANG. In an non-application-context (like in Akka-Actors or Unit-Tests) you don't have this info. So instead Play is using the Systems Default Locale, which defaulted to "en" on my machine. Since our app doesn't support the english language no translation file with ending ".en" was found.
This resulted in non translatable keys.

There are two possibilitys to make use of a specific language within actors.

- Create a conf/messages file which is the default-file if no other language-file is available for the set Locale.
- (my preffered way). Force the implicit Language by setting default Locale like this: `java.util.Locale.setDefault(new Locale("de"));`

I hope this might be useful for someone.